# Colorbox: how to do something after each slide loads?

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I'm using the [colorbox](https://github.com/jackmoore/colorbox) image slider and I want to be able to do something after each slide loads. Something like this:

> jQuery(document).on('afterSlide',function(){
>
> //do stuff like get the current slide url
>
> });

But from what I'm gathering there are no public events for individual slides like an 'afterSlide'.   Is there anyway to do this with the colorbox api, or am I missing something?